# Pass function with Dependancy Injection from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript

Component A accepts a function as in @Input() variable.  When the component's button is clicked, the function is called.

```
// arming-button.component.ts
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-arming-button',
  templateUrl: './arming-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arming-button.component.scss']
})
export class ArmingButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  confirmedFunction;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}

// arming-button.component.html
    <button type="button" (click)="confirmedFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

This doesn't work because the passed function may contain references to DI functions etc.  For example:

```
// other.component.ts
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-arming-button',
  templateUrl: './arming-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arming-button.component.scss']
})
export class ArmingButtonComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doSomething(): void {
    // arming-button component has no reference to this.http
    this.http.get('someUrl.com/stuff')
        .subscribe(response => console.log(response)); 
    }

}

// other.component.html
<app-arming-button [confirmedFunction]="doSomething"></app-arming-button>
```

How can I pass the function to the other component in a way that maintains internal function references?  I can think of some horrible hacky ways to do it, but none that really make the component re-usable.  Any clues would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Input and Output to achieve this i.e in your other.component.ts please use this code

```
doSomething(status) {
// Perform your operation
}
```

Other.component.html

```
<app-arming-button (confirmedFunction)="doSomething($event)"></app-arming-button>
```

Arming-button.component.ts

```
confirmedFunction = new EventEmitter<any>();

confirmedButtonClicked(){
this.confirmedFunction.emit(true);
}
```

Arming-button.component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="confirmedButtonClicked()">Click Me</button>
```

I think this helps you to achieve what you want.